# Router Standard ACL

Tags: routing, networking, acl, access-control

I was configuring **Standard ACL** on router 1841 on *Cisco Packet Tracer* with the help of command **access-list 1 permit 172.16.40.3 0.0.0.0** and **access-list 1 deny 172.16.40.4 0.0.0.0** and then I applied this ACL to interface f0/0 which should have allowed the host 172.16.40.3 and blocked the host 172.16.40.4 instead it blocked the entire network 172.16.40.0 network not a single host can ping to the 172.16.10.1 router even the neighbour routers are not able to ping to 172.16.10.1 router. What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use wildcards. What you did permits 172.16.40.3 to talk to 0.0.0.0 (invalid address) and the implied *deny any any* blocks anything else.

Try

```
permit 172.16.40.3/32 0.0.0.0/0
deny 172.16.40.4/32 0.0.0.0/0
permit any any
```

or

```
permit 172.16.40.3 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
deny 172.16.40.4 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
permit any any
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested to me but the router is not recognising /32 and /0 mask I think that's the old syntax.

Comment: @user60845 I've added the lengthy wildcard syntax as well.

Comment: Tired that too again it's a old syntax 

Comment: Hey man problem solved I was applying the ACL on inbound connection that's why it was not letting other devices to communicate to the router. As I applied the ACL on outbound connection the problem solved. Thank-you very much for replying I really appreciate that 